# How to schedule Github workflow only if there is code change

Tags: github, github-actions

I have an ASP.NET 6 based project hosted on Github.
I added a workflow that would run it every day and create a release. However, I only want to run the workflow "if there is a code change"

I don't want to create a new release if there is no change.

Here is a stripped down version of my workflow

```
name: Build and publish preview
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 14 * * *'

jobs:
```

How to add a rule that say only run if there was new code changes (from direct commit or code merge?)

Comment: Yes it is possible :) You'd have to first fetch the previous release, check what commit that was based on and then compare if there were any commits since then.